# How to set up Kafka for Hyperledger Fabric 1.0?

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I want to set up Kafka and am looking at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/bddtests/dc-orderer-kafka.yml

I have downloaded the latest fabric-release.zip and have grepped with no success: I cannot figure out where the following bash variables for the orderer in dc-orderer-kafka.yml are initialized or what they should be:

```
- ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=${ORDERER1_ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID}
- ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=${ORDERER1_ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR}
- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=${ORDERER1_ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY}
- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=${ORDERER1_ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE}
- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=${ORDERER1_ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS}
```

Does anyone have an example of default values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you give me e a guide on how to configure hyperledger fabric to work with kafka ?

Comment: Spent a couple of weeks in July trying to make a first-network example with Kafka work, and again a half-day this week with version 1.0.2. Not convinced it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example you were looking for:

```
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
  # enabled TLS
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
```

Found at [docker-compose-base.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/d9c320297bd2a4eff2eb253ce84dc431ef860972/examples/e2e_cli/base/docker-compose-base.yaml)